# Delete record from table that has related table

Tags: ms-access

I am working in MS Access and I getting "cannot delete from specified tables" errors.

My tables are:

```
Orders 
OrderDetails 
Products 
OrderView
```

OrderView is a query table with data is from OrderDetails and Products tables respectively.

I am trying to delete records from OrderDetails where the productId matches my productId in the a gridview.

My sql statement is:

```
DELETE * FROM OrderDetails WHERE productId=@productId
```

I am getting @productId from the grid view

This is my grid view markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataSourceID="row3" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" 
GridLines="Horizontal"
DataKeyNames="oProductId"

width="100%"
>
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="oProductId" HeaderText="Product Id" 
        SortExpression="oProductId" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="pProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" 
        SortExpression="pProductName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="oQty" HeaderText="Quantity" 
        SortExpression="oQty" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="oPrice" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="oPrice" 
        DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="oAmt" HeaderText="Amount" 
        SortExpression="oAmt" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
        <ItemTemplate>

          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


</Columns>
<FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
```

Comment: What error message? If it is about a related table, you need to check your database design. It should be possible to delete from an order detail table without causing a referential integrity error.

Comment: error msg:cannot delete from specified tables"

Comment: Your message says `tables` but your delete statement shows one table. Are you sure you are running against OrderDetails and not OrderView? Have you tried running the statement in MS Access?

Comment: OrderView is a query not a table my mistake, and when an order is added it will be added to Orders, OrderDetails

Comment: Have you tried the query in MS Access `DELETE * FROM OrderDetails WHERE productId=1` where 1 is a valid ID?

Comment: Hi its worked on my MS Access

Comment: Have you got the right permissions on the file and folder? Can you run the exact same query in asp.net?

Comment: rEMOU its resolved thanks the conn path was not correct

Answer (score 0):

How many records are in that table? How many records are you trying to delete?

I run into the overflow error when I try to delete more than 30,000 records out of a table containing 1 million + records. This seems to be an Access limitation. Access cannot handle enough memory to hold all records in memory and do a search and delete while keeping the deleted data for the purpose of rolling back in event of error. That's my best guess.
I have tackled this issue using 2 strategies: 1) Do not insert any records into a large table unless absolutely sure I need them inserted right now. Use a temp table or global var array to temporarily store values. 2) Delete in small chunks. E.G. DELETE ... WHERE ID BETWEEN 20000 AND 25000. Make sure the column you name in the WHERE clause is an Indexed column. I include such a statement in a loop, incrementing the 2 vals in the BETWEEN phrase.